# How to remove docker images based on name?

Tags: docker

I want to delete all versions of docker images with names that contain a given string (`imagename`). 
I have tried the below, but it doesn't seem to work:

`docker images | grep 'imagename' |  xargs -I {} docker rmi`

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Try the following:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep 'imagename')
```

or, alternatively:

```
docker rmi $(docker images 'completeimagename' -a -q)
```

In Windows PowerShell:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}"|findstr "imagename")
```

Comment: Current version of Docker support this (no grep): docker rmi $(docker images 'imagename')

Comment: Current version of Docker seems to support this - maybe I'm missing something? -  docker rmi 'imagename'

Comment: @Charlie I think most people are looking for a way to match all images that match '*imagename*' rather than a single image named exactly 'imagename'.

Comment: I am getting this following error: "docker rmi requires at least 1 argument."

Comment: @michali It means that there is no matching image returned.Can you verify that there is a matching entry present by just running : `docker images |grep 'imagename'`

Comment: Since grep isn't available on windows here is powershell alternative: `docker images | Select-String -Pattern "^eclipse/*" |   Where {$_ -match "\s[a-z0-9]{12}\s"} | Foreach{ docker rmi $Matches[0].trim()}` where you have to change the "^ecliplse/*" pattern to your own tast:)

Comment: Note this doesn't work anymore, see below answers which print the image tags only.

Comment: How to remove images that has no name like: <none>

Comment: @mece1390 Checkout how to remove dangling images : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#show-untagged-images-dangling

Answer (score 127):

Slightly more exact version - grepping only on the repository name:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep 'imagename')
```

Comment: Grep can be replaced by docker `--filter` flag. ```docker images --filter=reference='imagename:*'```

Answer (score 34):

`docker images` actually uses the first positional argument as an image name/id to filter for. No grep's and awk's required. The `-q` option will return only the matching images IDs which can be fed to `docker rmi`.

```
docker rmi --force $(docker images -q 'imagename' | uniq)
```

The `uniq` is required to remove duplicates, in case you have the same image tagged differently.

Comment: This is surely the best option today. To keep with the consistency of the question though the imagename should be in quotes.

Comment: This answer doesn't handle wildcards, only the exact image name.  Also `docker images -q 'imagename'`  returns the IMAGE ID (not the name).

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I've been saying.

Answer (score 27):

```
docker rmi $(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep 'imagename')
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Bits of random code could be dangerous.

Comment: ```docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}``` filters the output so only repo & tag are shown (ie ```foo:latest```).  ```grep 'imagename``` filters those lines to only those images that contain ```imagename```. Putting that in ```$()``` evaluates that & passes to the outer ```docker rmi``` which removes those images that were matched.

Comment: Expanding on the above, you can delete all tagged images corresponding to an exact image name as follows:
`docker rmi -f $(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' --filter=reference='imagename:*')'`

Comment: on windows "grep" does not exist (cmd or powershell)
The following can be used on widows
`docker rmi $( docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | Select-String -Pattern 'imagename')`

Answer (score 10):

I find my answer more simple.

Example, your image name is `python_image`.

**Then your code should be**:

`docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference='python_image' --format "{{.ID}}")`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can we do this for multiple images based on wildcard name?

Comment: As pedantic as this sounds, the same doesn't work for `podman` due to some (apparent) bug. Docs tend to suggest that `reference` is the same as NAME in `docker images` output... but that seems to not always be true. Thus, `docker rmi -f $(docker images '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep "foo" --color=never)` seems to be more robust, because you know what you're filtering on, you can debug it. Not the case with the unclear "reference" variable.

Answer (score 10):

Simply you can add `--force` at the end of the command. Like:

`sudo docker rmi <docker_image_id> --force`

To make it more **intelligent** you can stop any running container before remove the image:

```
sudo docker stop $(docker ps | grep <your_container_name> | awk '{print $1}')

sudo docker rm $(docker ps | grep <your_container_name> | awk '{print $1}')

sudo docker rmi $(docker images | grep <your_image_name> | awk '{print $3}') --force
```

In `docker ps`, ***$1*** is the 1st column i.e. docker container id 
and **$3** is the 3rd column i.e. docker image id

Answer (score 6):

For me worked (**Docker version 19.03.5**):

```
docker rmi $(docker images 'imagename' -q)
```

The command "**docker images 'imagename' -q**" will list all the images id of the single quoted argument so concatenating it with **docker rmi** (or **docker rmi -f** for forcing) it will remove all images with selected name

Answer (score 4):

I also got another concise answer. The only change was to remove the unnecessary `-I {}` flag.

`docker images | grep 'imagename' |  xargs docker rmi`

Comment: OMG thanks! nothing else on this page worked for me, either because they did not read the OP about requiring pattern matching on name rather than reference, or they offered solutions requiring inline command expansion. Using xargs made this easy.

Answer (score 4):

`docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="IMAGENAME:TAG")`

for example if I have the following images

```
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abcdefg/hij                   7.0.0-beta-4.0      3128835950cd        7 days ago          51.4MB
abcdefg/hij-action            7.0.0-beta-4.0      42a7255beb74        7 days ago          97.4MB
abcdefg/hij-test              7.0.0-beta-4.0      17246aed35d0        7 days ago          97.4MB
abcdefg/hij-server            7.0.0-beta-4.0      42c45e561f2c        7 days ago          335MB
abcdefg/hij-init              7.0.0-beta-3.0      f648bb622933        7 days ago          55.2MB
abcdefg/hij-dir               7.0.0-beta-3.0      0db07d3aaccf        7 days ago          97.4MB
abcdefg/hij-mount             7.0.0-beta-3.0      18d1c0e1502c        4 weeks ago         33.7MB
```

Then `docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="abcd*:*4.0")` will remove the first four images.

Further information please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: works, but would be better to add '-q' to the docker images command:  
  
`docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter=reference="IMAGENAME:TAG")`

Comment: TroyFolger is right, you must add '-q' if you don't want an error in the result. So, if you want te remove all gitlab-13 images: `docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter=reference="sameersbn/gitlab:13*")`

Comment: @troyfolger this produce error "Error response from daemon: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" for me.. using docker version: 20.10.17, build 100c701

Answer (score 3):

```
docker rmi `docker images | awk '$1 ~ /imageName/ {print $3}'`
```

This will remove all the images by name "imageName".
In some cases this may give an error like "image is referenced in one or more repositories". In that case use force delete.

```
docker rmi -f `docker images | awk '$1 ~ /imageName/ {print $3}'`
```

Another way can be:

```
docker images | awk '{ OFS = ":" }$1 ~ /imageName/ {print $1,$2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I wasn't able to use any of the given answers here. Here's what worked for me.

`docker images | grep \"gcr.io/kubernetes-learn-197422/last-week-weather-service\" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi`

`awk '{print $3}'` is an important part. It extracts id from the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker rmi $(docker image ls repo/image_name* | awk {'print $1":"$2'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Put together a solution to this question to meet my needs, that wasn't posted previously.

I wanted to match locally built images: `library/myapp` that I've renamed, tagged, and pushed to a private repo: `myrepo.org/library/myapp`.  Once they are pushed, I want to clean up the local docker reg.

And I don't care if nothing is found or the command throws an error. Thus added `|| true` at the end for inclusion into scripts.

```
docker rmi $(docker image ls */library/myApp --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}') || true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
docker images | grep 'DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME' | xargs -l bash -c 'docker rmi $0:$1' | xargs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
docker image ls | grep 'repository-name' |  awk '{ print $3 }'  | while read -r line ; do docker image rm $line; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This currently works for me;

```
docker rmi $(docker images |  awk '{if ($1 ~ "^image_prefix") print $1":"$2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor remark:
From what we are experiencing, it seems you're - since docker 18.03 - no longer able to remove untagged images based on just the name. You either need to use the name+tag as stated above or use the ID.

```
docker images --format={{.ID}} | xargs -I % sh -c 'docker rmi --force % 2>&1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Aditya's answer, you can also create a bash function to remove images at ease. Put this function to your `~/.profile`. Create a new shell session or source it by `source ~/.profile`.

```
function drmi() {
    docker images | grep $1 |  xargs docker rmi
}
```

Usage:

```
drmi golang
```

Answer (score 0):

Informational:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" |grep imagename |grep none)
```

Give this error:

> Error response from daemon: invalid reference format

Probably because my images looks like this:

```
hostname:5000/imagename:<none>
```

I had to use the image id and do this command:

```
docker rmi `docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.ID}}" |grep imagename |grep none |cut -d ' ' -f2`
```

To remove exited containers:

```
docker container rm `docker container ls -a --format "{{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Status}}" |grep Exited |grep imagename|cut -d ' ' -f1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my [preferred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676380/5362795) but with a variable instead:

```
docker rmi --force "$(docker images -q $repository | uniq)"
```

And this could be used in a Jenkins pipeline:

```
sh(script: 'docker rmi --force "$(docker images -q $repository | uniq)"', returnStdout: true)
```

I preferred this option instead of removing through the tag:

```
$ docker rmi test:latest
```

This is because, as the [docs say](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/) and I verified, *"using this command with the tag as a parameter only removes the tag. If the tag is the only one for the image, both the image and the tag are removed."*

Answer (score 0):

finally, this worked for me

shell:  docker images  --format {% raw %}'{{.ID}} - {{.Repository}}'{%endraw%} | grep {{ app_name }} | cut -d'-' -f1 | xargs docker rmi -f

{{ app_name }} is regex of docker image name

Answer (score -1):

To remove image from my local I used following command it worked!!

```
docker rmi imagename
```

When I was using image name in single quote it didn't worked.