# How to remove docker images based on name using Jenkins on windows node

Tags: docker, batch-file, jenkins

Base on the question from here

> [How to remove docker images based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084044/how-to-remove-docker-images-based-on-name)

I tried modify the solution with bat inside Jenkins windows slave node. I only want to remove the images by name. My manual running command is

```
for /F "tokens=3" %a in ('docker images ^| findstr "my_image" ') do docker rmi %a
```

It runs successfully in cmd at the slave node manually. I plot this to the jenkinfile with IMAGE_NAME = my_image

```
bat " for /F \"tokens=3\" %%a in ('docker images ^^^| findstr \"${IMAGE_NAME}\" ') do docker rmi %%a "
```

After running on jenkins, I see the console output is

```
C:\Program Files\jenkins\workspace\my_image>for /F "tokens=3" %a in ('docker images ^| findstr "my_image" ') do docker rmi %a
```

The translation looks fine as it is identifical with the manual type. However the outcome from Jenkins is

```
"docker images" requires at most 1 argument.
```

Any idea why it works manually but not in Jenkinsfile? I have a feeling that jenkins did not execute the findstr. Will be nice if someone and point out what is the issue.

Comment: @Mofi ^| does not work as I am using it inside a Jenkinsfile and need to escape.

Comment: I finally setting with  bat " for /F \"tokens=1\" %%a in ('docker images --filter \"dangling=true\" -q') do docker rmi %%a" just to move out the <none> first.